# Class contains pointer to base class but I don't want it to. (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, polymorphism

A bizarre question title, but I didn't know how else to describe the situation compactly.

Recently I have been asking questions regarding producing software for audio synthesis. This question is in regards to a specific "issue" I'm having. My code compiles and works fine; its just a "bit odd" if you will.

I have a class which contains a pointer to a base class. I will detail a minimal example to show what is going on in more detail.

```
class SynthNoteBase
{

    // example content
    virtual
    double Sample() = 0;

}; // just for base class pointer

class SynthNoteA : public SynthNoteBase
{

};

class SynthNoteB : public SynthNoteBase
{

}; // define two different types of note -
   // these will synthesize different sounds
```

Each class `SynthNote*` has a member, for example, `Play()` or `Sample()` which returns samples to "be played"/"recorded in an audio file"/etc.

Now, I have a `Synthesizer` object (class) which contains many `SynthesizerKey` objects. Each `SynthesizerKey` class contains a pointer to the base class `SynthNoteBase`.

**Explanation:** The "`Synthesizer`" has many different `Key`s, just like a real synthesizer would. These `Key` objects will have a `Play()` method, or similar. The main program may read data from an input source (keyboard/file) and decide which `Key`s to play. One may want different sounds for each Key. (At the minimum, one will require different frequencies of notes to be played. The frequency would be a parameter inside `SynthNote*`.)

So far all is well, except when constructing `SynthesizerKey` objects.

```
class SynthesizerKey
{

protected:

    SynthNoteBase *m_synthnotebase_ptr;

public:

    SynthesizerKey(SynthNoteBase* const synthnote)
        : m_synthnotebase_ptr{synthnote}
    {
        
    }

    virtual
    ~SynthesizerKey()
    {
        delete m_synthnotebase_ptr; // could be a problem
    }

    void Play()
    {
        m_synthnotebase_ptr->Play(); // or whatever
    }

}
```

The "problem" occurs when calling the constructor.

```
SynthesizerKey key1(new SynthNoteA(...parameters...)); // had to use new here
// but we never delete! (delete hidden in destructor)
```

I appreciate that this isn't really a "problem" per-se, but it does produce some seriously awful code where the end user is allocating memory with new in a constructor call, but never appears to delete said memory.

Is my question clear? What alternative might there be to this situation?

Perhaps this could be solved using smart pointers? I suspect that this is only really a partial resolution, in that we can use smart pointers to hide the "new" part as well as the "delete" part... Not sure that's better, actually.

What does SO think?

## Edit 1

(In response to below answer.)

I have attempted this solution:

```
class SynthesizerKey
{
    std::unique_ptr<SynthNoteBase> m_note;

    SynthesizerKey(const SynthNoteBase& note)
        : m_note(new ...) // ah: can't do this!
        // don't know what type to allocate with new?
    {
    }
}
```

But I can't allocate memory, because I will be allocating storage for the base class type not a derived class type.

Comment: Did you make sure ~SynthesizerKey() is called at some point? Also I don't see colon in `SynthesizerKey(SynthNoteBase* const synthnote)
        m_synthnotebase_ptr{synthnote}`. Is typo in your question or it is missed in the code?

Comment: @mvidelgauz The destructor will be called at some point, but the "problem" here is the user never calls `delete` explicitly... Also corrected typo, thanks.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what `delete` you expect a "user" to call. Is he/she expected to delete of SynthesizerKey object(s)?

Comment: move constructors?

Comment: @mvidelgauz Traditionally, if the user is responsible for a call to `new`, they would usually be expected to `delete` at some point "manually" if you will, later

Comment: To all, could PIMPL be used to some effect here?

Answer (score 0):

For polymorphism to work you really have no choice than to use pointers.

A possible "solution" to at least *hide* the allocation might be to pass a constant reference to the base object as argument to the `SynthesizerKey` constructor and handle the memory allocation in the `SynthesizerKey` constructor initializer list and rely on the ["virtual constructor" (or *cloning*) pattern](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors) to copy the object.

Also I recommend you look into using [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of using "raw" pointers. Then at least you don't have to worry about deletion of the objects.

---

The ["virtual constructor" (or *cloning*) pattern](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors) in your case would be something like this:

```
class SynthNoteBase
{

    // example content
    virtual
    double Sample() = 0;

    virtual SynthNoteBase* clone() = 0;
};

class SynthNoteA : public SynthNoteBase
{
    SynthNoteBase* clone()
    {
        return new SynthNoteA(*this);  // Allocates and invokes the copy-constructor
    }
};

class SynthNoteB : public SynthNoteBase
{
    SynthNoteBase* clone()
    {
        return new SynthNoteB(*this);  // Allocates and invokes the copy-constructor
    }
};

class SynthesizerKey
{
    std::unique_ptr<SynthNoteBase> m_note;

    SynthesizerKey(const SynthNoteBase& note)
        : m_note(note.clone())  // Clone the note, invokes copy-constructor correctly
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: I've immediately hit a wall. See Edit 1!

Comment: I'm not sure this is much of an improvement at the calling point: instead of his version `SynthesizerKey key1(new SynthNoteA(...parameters...));` you're now letting him do `SynthesizerKey key1(SynthNoteA(...parameters...));` So... the `new` is still happening, but it's hidden.

Comment: @JohnBurger The only other way I can think of would be to make the constructor take a [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) but then the constructor (or class) needs to be a template and you need to specify the `SynthNoteX` class explicitly, not making it much better. If polymorphism is wanted, then sooner or later an object must be dynamically allocated. And unless using overloaded constructors (one for each `SynthNodeX` concrete class, nothing I recommend) one must specify the note type some way or another.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes the simplest is the best - and his `Key(new Note(...params...));` seems the simplest.

Comment: @JohnBurger Hidding the `new` is exactly the point of the question

Comment: @JohnBurger Ah I think I understand why you don't like this solution so much... I'm not sure how I feel about it either (yet) - it is certainly an improvement however so thanks to Joachim for the efforts

Answer (score 0):

You may represent the note member as a std::unique_ptr and pass a note (derived from SynthNoteBase) by value or reference to a constructor of SynthesizerKey:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class SynthNoteBase
{
    public:
    virtual ~SynthNoteBase() {}
    virtual void Play() const = 0;
};

class SynthNoteA : public SynthNoteBase
{
    public:
    void Play() const override { std::cout << "Play A\n"; };
};

class SynthesizerKey
{
protected:
    std::unique_ptr<SynthNoteBase> m_synthnotebase_ptr;

public:
    template <typename Note>
    SynthesizerKey(Note&& note)
    :   m_synthnotebase_ptr{
            std::make_unique<typename std::decay<Note>::type>(
                std::forward<Note>(note))}
    {}

    void Play() const { m_synthnotebase_ptr->Play();  }
};

int main()
{
    SynthesizerKey keyA{SynthNoteA()};
    keyA.Play();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3728501 The constructor of  SynthesizerKey is taking any note (derived from SynthNoteBase) and copies or moves it to a new instance of std::unique_ptr<SynthNoteBase>.

Comment: What does the stuff in the `SynthesizerKey` constructor with `std::decay` and `std::forward` do?

Comment: @user3728501 Simplified: The decay extracts the underlaying note type (e.g.: Note& -> Note). The forward  allows forwarding arguments as copyable or movable arguments (depending on their type) .

Answer (score 0):

If you do do this, **MAKE SURE YOU MAKE THE `Base` CLASS' DESTRUCTOR VIRTUAL TOO!**
If you delete through `Base *`, you want to make sure that the derived destructor is called first!

Is your "seriously awful" comment about the length/wordiness of what you have to type? If so, I don't see how you're going to resolve it: you need what you need.

If it's a stylistic thing ("There's the `new`, where's the `delete`?"), take comfort in the knowledge that doing it this way:

```
Minder(new Child());
```

means you're obviously 'surrendering' the pointer to `Minder` to take care of - it's its problem now!

---

You've basically got three options: Whole-object, reference-to-object, and pointer-to-object.

1. **Whole-object:** Pass a reference to the object into the constructor, take a local copy, and let the passed-in copy be destructed.

   > The problem here is that you don't know the type of the passed-in object, only that it's a `Base`, so any `Base` copy will be a "slice" of the original - losing the virtual-ness. Also: pure methods prevent Whole-`Base` objects.
2. **Reference-to-object:** If you only remember a reference, then you're giving up the option of managing said object's memory.

   > You *could* do a `delete &reference;` - but then you might as well have kept a pointer instead.
3. **Pointer-to-object:** This is your solution, and I don't see anything wrong with it.

I do not believe that you should use a `smartptr` - what's the point? The pointer is only in one place; there's the only place it will be accessed; the destructor is going to `delete` it; problem solved.

A `smartptr` is used where the ownership of an object is unclear over the lifetime of the object. It gets passed around a lot; copies are made; so when is the object finally done? Here, the lifetime of the object is fully known, with one passing of ownership at creation time. Don't complicate it.

Virtual constructors are a solution - at the expense of having to write a `Clone()` method in *every* derived class. You still need to construct the derived object to pass it around - letting others take a `Clone()` of it only so that you immediately destruct it seems like an awful lot of effort.

Comment: I agree with your comments on smart pointers. I also forgot to add `virtual` to the destructor... What is this strange `Clone()` method of which you speak? Can you explain that with an example?

Comment: In the base class, have a pure virtual method called `virtual Base *Clone() = 0;`. In all derived classes, define `virtual Derived *Clone() { return new Derived(*this);` (of course replacing `Derived`. That means that given a `Base`, you can get a full copy of the whole object.